# ECLIPSE: How to export the smallest jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, xtext

My project's jar file size is getting bigger and bigger as more stuff is added into it. I am wondering if someone has tips on how to generate a smaller jar file.

I export it as a Runnable JAR file and the library handling is Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated JAR.

In the Properties - Java Compiler - Classfile Generation, everything is unticked.

With these options, I was able to save approx 3MB of space. And I am hoping I can save more by removing the unneeded data.

My .jar file has a .java._trace files in it. How can I remove this from the jar file?

A .xtend and .class file is also there for each class. Since the .class file is just a conversion of the .xtend, I want to remove either one of these from the jar file. How can I achieve this?

I would appreciate any tips and tricks that can help me reduce the size of the jar file.

Comment: I don't recommend using it in production, but you could try an obfuscator like yGuard, look at the logs to see what it did, and use that to remove unnecessary code.

Comment: You can also add exclusions within the maven jar plugin. Exclude all *.java_trace, for example.

Comment: @ccleve If I add the exclusion in the maven jar plugin, would the jar file still work?

Comment: If you exclude something that your app doesn't need, then the jar should work fine.

Comment: @ccleve in Eclipse, under Window - Preferences - Maven, there is no option to specify to exclude certain files. Where can I find such functionality in Eclipse?

Comment: Edit the pom. Add an entry for the Maven jar plugin. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/ There is an optional <excludes> section in the plugin XML.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude the source code file from the generated JAR file of an Xtext based project (and I think any Eclipse plug-in as well), open the plug-in.xml file which is located in the projects root folder. Navigate to the tab "Build" and make sure that your source folders are not selected. Normally there are three source code folders "src", "src-gen" and "xtend-gen". Also the "doc" folder which contains generated java doc is not necessary.

Comment: Hi, I only want to exclude specific files. My src folder contains java and xtend files. Is there a way to include java files, but exclude the xtend files?